# javascript asynchronous json http request in Model View structure using jQuery .when() .done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous, httprequest

I am trying to solve a problem where an asynchronous json request is made but the rest of the script runs before the request is completed which breaks the code. To complicate matters this is done in a MVC structure...

I make an asynchronous json request in the Controller which gets a json file and populates a model object with the data, basically:

```
model {
        data: {}
}

controller  {
    init: function(){
                function loadJSON(callback) {
                var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
                xobj.open('GET', 'js/resumeInfo.json', true); 
                xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                        // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will
                        //NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in 
                        //asynchronous mode

                        callback(xobj.responseText);
                    }
                };
                xobj.send(null);
            };

            loadJSON((response) => {
                // Parse JSON string into object
                this.JSONdata = JSON.parse(response);

                // anything I want to do with model.data from here is all
                // good, works fine...

                model.dataBank = this.JSONdata;

                view.init();

            });

           // ... but anything outside the above ^ scope will execute before the
           //asynchronous request is completed and produce an 'undefined' error
           //when trying to access model.data.
    }

}

view {
        // no good trying to access model.data here either because it executes
       // before json http request has completed...
}
```

I have tried using jQuery ( which is passed into this module as a parameter ) .when and .done, but doesn't seem to work because it is not picking up the callback response.

Appreciate any ideas about how to access that call back response for $ .when .done?

Comment: If you work with the `model` inside your callback function (or in `view.init()` as you call that from the callback) your code will work fine as it is

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes that works well. However it seems more like a 'work around'. In a MVC layout, a VIewinitalize method shouldn't really be called from an inner function in a Contoller method, should it?...And it would still be useful to figure out how to access that callback response or Promise to use with  a jQuery `.when .done.` method.